# Signal path switching for effect circuits

Tags: switches, relay, design, cmos, component-selection

I'm trying to build a method of switching signal order with three circuits in a rack unit.

I've been researching different methods, using relays, using CMOS etc but I'm getting a bit overwhelmed and lost. I don't have a lot of technical experience with electronics apart from building kits and using an Arduino every now and then.

Say circuits are A, B and C; I would like to order them ABC, CAB, BAC, ACB.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on this? Any recommended reading on CMOS or even a chip recommendation?

Thanks for reading!

Edit: Added a picture to make it clearer, all signals are analog (line-level).
[image]

Comment: Hello! You don't specify what kind of circuits are A, B and C, if the signals are analog or digital, what you expect at the output etc...

Comment: Apologies, all signals are analog (around line level, audio).

Comment: So you are looking for some sort of matrix to switch any of N inputs to each particular circuit. Or actually X number of N to 1 multiplexers.

Comment: That sounds about right, basically the input gets amplified and fed into a sub board that allows me to chain together three other effects boards. The output of that goes to a limiter and then to a jack. I could just use jacks for each effects board as a modular patcher but was hoping for a more elegant solution with a rotary switch, ideally.

Comment: Wait.. you are time sequencing them? Or mixing them? Your definition is really muddy.

Comment: Well it's time based I guess. So signal gets sent to Ain then from Aout to Bin then Bout to Cin to Cout to OUT. I'd like to be able to switch between the order of A B and C via a rotary switch.

Comment: That's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a continuation of Trevor's answer. So the design will be fairly similar.

I'm not sure how much you like relays, but I prefer transistors to do their job (whenever possible). Because of the physical size, price and energy consumption.

I'm using two N-MOSFETS as a [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate), but in order to properly open them and close them you will most likely need 12 V and -12 V, those can easily be made with a [charge pump and an oscillator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5.0000000000000004e-8+2.803162489452614+50+5+50%0Aw+1136+288+1200+288+2%0Aw+1136+176+1200+176+2%0Ap+1200+176+1200+288+1+0%0Aw+928+128+960+128+0%0Ac+928+176+960+176+0+0.000001+-3.812292278845405%0Ad+960+128+960+176+1+0.5%0Ac+928+288+960+288+0+0.000001+3.2598418134849307%0Aw+928+240+960+240+0%0Ad+960+288+960+240+1+0.5%0Aw+1088+176+1136+176+0%0Aw+1136+288+1088+288+0%0Ad+1024+128+1024+176+1+0.5%0Ac+992+176+1024+176+0+0.000001+-2.9648458888036338%0Aw+992+128+1024+128+0%0Ac+960+128+992+128+0+0.000001+-2.8670008110501444%0Ad+992+176+992+128+1+0.5%0Aw+960+176+992+176+0%0Ad+1024+288+1024+240+1+0.5%0Ac+960+240+992+240+0+0.000001+3.3311232570108364%0Aw+992+240+1024+240+0%0Ac+992+288+1024+288+0+0.000001+2.62388610638562%0Ad+992+240+992+288+1+0.5%0Aw+992+288+960+288+0%0Ag+336+320+336+336+0%0Ac+336+288+336+320+0+1e-9+2.0906497066135152%0Ag+336+224+336+240+0%0Ac+336+192+336+224+0+1e-9+4.449441517560208%0Aw+272+192+272+256+0%0Aw+336+256+336+288+0%0Ar+272+288+336+288+0+10000%0Aw+272+256+272+288+0%0Ad+336+256+272+256+1+0.5%0Aw+272+160+272+192+0%0Ar+336+192+272+192+0+10000%0Aw+336+160+336+192+0%0Ad+272+160+336+160+1+0.5%0AR+384+144+384+96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+384+208+384+240+0%0Aw+384+176+384+208+0%0Af+336+160+384+160+1+1.5+2%0Aw+464+208+384+208+0%0Ag+384+272+384+288+0%0Af+336+256+384+256+0+1.5+2%0Af+528+272+576+272+0+1.5+2%0Ag+576+288+576+304+0%0Aw+656+224+576+224+0%0Af+528+176+576+176+1+1.5+2%0Aw+576+192+576+224+0%0Aw+576+224+576+256+0%0Ad+464+176+528+176+1+0.5%0Aw+528+176+528+208+0%0Ar+528+208+464+208+0+10000%0Aw+464+176+464+208+0%0Ad+528+272+464+272+1+0.5%0Aw+464+272+464+304+0%0Ar+464+304+528+304+0+10000%0Aw+528+272+528+304+0%0Aw+464+208+464+272+0%0Ac+528+208+528+240+0+1e-9+2.388069597732217%0Ag+528+240+528+256+0%0Ac+528+304+528+336+0+1e-9+0.0001989559447674823%0Ag+528+336+528+352+0%0Af+720+288+768+288+0+1.5+2%0Ag+768+304+768+320+0%0Af+720+192+768+192+1+1.5+2%0Aw+768+208+768+240+0%0Aw+768+240+768+272+0%0Ad+656+192+720+192+1+0.5%0Aw+720+192+720+224+0%0Ar+720+224+656+224+0+10000%0Aw+656+192+656+224+0%0Ad+720+288+656+288+1+0.5%0Aw+656+288+656+320+0%0Ar+656+320+720+320+0+10000%0Aw+720+288+720+320+0%0Aw+656+224+656+288+0%0Ac+720+224+720+256+0+1e-9+5.000532841717848%0Ag+720+256+720+272+0%0Ac+720+320+720+352+0+1e-9+1.7364417522409323%0Ag+720+352+720+368+0%0Aw+272+400+272+288+0%0Aw+384+144+576+144+0%0Aw+576+144+576+160+0%0Aw+576+144+768+144+0%0Aw+768+144+768+176+0%0Aw+272+400+848+400+0%0Aw+848+240+848+400+0%0Ac+896+240+928+240+0+0.000001+4.698538612257485%0Ag+928+288+928+304+0%0Ag+928+176+928+192+0%0Ac+896+128+928+128+0+0.000001+0.9075980660394138%0Ad+928+240+928+288+1+0.5%0Ad+928+176+928+128+1+0.5%0Aw+896+128+896+240+0%0Aw+768+240+848+240+0%0Aw+896+240+848+240+0%0Aw+1024+176+1056+176+0%0Ad+1056+176+1056+128+1+0.5%0Ac+1024+128+1056+128+0+0.000001+-2.5106599165639865%0Aw+1056+128+1088+128+0%0Ac+1056+176+1088+176+0+0.000001+-2.6277255257748866%0Ad+1088+128+1088+176+1+0.5%0Aw+1056+288+1024+288+0%0Ad+1056+240+1056+288+1+0.5%0Ac+1056+288+1088+288+0+0.000001+2.5648040718828584%0Aw+1056+240+1088+240+0%0Ac+1024+240+1056+240+0+0.000001+2.7281075989591193%0Ad+1088+288+1088+240+1+0.5%0Ao+2+32+0+4098+40+0.1+0+1%0Ao+36+2+0+20481+5+0.8+1+2+36+3%0Ao+76+1+0+4099+10+0.025+2+2+76+3%0A).

[image]

I hate seeing negative voltages at the top of the schematic, but since the [Falstad Circuit JS](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) doesn't support proper wire dragging I decided that it was not worth my time. Had this been something job related then I'd redesign it with -12 V at bottom and 12 V at the top. I realized my wrong doing very late at the design stage.

Here's the [text](https://pastebin.com/nhK0sqPN) if you want to interact with the button at the bottom.

If you want to simulate, press the [Circuit JS](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) link, when you are at Circuit JS, click file at the upper left. Choose "file > import from text" and copy and paste the text from the text link. This is the first time I've made a schematic with an URL that's too long. Oh well.

---

EDIT: Realized you don't need the PMOS at the bottom if you connect your switch to 12 V instead of 0 V.

So it should look more like this:

[image]

If you look at the output, I changed the pull down resistors so they are correct.

This is the design I'd solder onto a PCB and be happy with. But I'm no audiophile, I can't even tell if someone sings bad or not. Music ain't my thang.

Here's the [text](https://pastebin.com/7QHLugYN) for this circuit if you want to test it out.

Comment: +1 Though audiophiles purists would point out solid-state switches are never truly off, so you always get a little cross-talk esp if the inputs are sufficiently high impedance.. That's why I suggested reed relays. I'm not keen on those either, but they are cheap and easy for the hobbyist ;)

Comment: True *audiophiles* should abhor effect circuits because they create distortion.

Comment: @Trevor I doubt they can tell the difference, if they hear any difference it's probably  some placebo effect.

Comment: LOL true @HarrySvensson ;)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and taking the time to simulate the circuit, really appreciate that. 
The cost of relays and the power draw is certainly a concern so this looks like a great method to counter that. I'll be running this off a 15+/- switching supply but I imagine the circuit concept is the same?

Comment: @MathsThief Yes, just make sure you look at the datasheet for your MOSFET you'll be using, the important parameter would be the absolute maximum rating of the \$V_{GS}\$. Most MOSFET's I've come across are able to withstand ±15 V.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I've done some reading about the MOSFET setup and was thinking it could be done with a few 4066 CMOS chips? They appear to be a quad SPST switch package. Would this work the same way, switching on/off when taken high/low?
Thanks again!

Comment: @MathsThief Those are way closer to Trevor's answer than mine, so he should get the correct answer if you choose to use the 4066 CMOS chips. - If you look closely at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b-q1.pdf) you will see on the front page it says ± 7.5 V, this will be problematic for you. The input range says that you need to cross 70% of \$V_{DD}\$ for a signal to register as high. And that you may not surpass \$V_{DD}+0.5\$ V. So if you are going to use it then get ± 7.5 V supplied somewhere. And keep in mind that a logic high is above 0.7×7.5 = 5.25 and less than 8 V

Comment: @MathsThief Also, the signal room that you are trying to route through your circuit can only live between -7.5 V and +7.5V with that 4066 chip, if it goes outside of it, it will be clipped. Using the MOSFET solution allows your signal to be between -15 V and 15-\$V_{GS(TH)}\$ ≃13 V (for a typical logic level MOSFET). I would not use the 4066 chip. - Oh right, an extra note regarding the MOSFET solution, if your signal is at -15 V, then \$V_{GS}\$ is at 30 V.

Comment: @MathsThief last comment, the resistance of the 4066 chip is insane. 470 Ω if you feed it ±2.5 V, 180 Ω if you feed it ±5 V, 125 Ω if you feed it ±7.5 V. So whatever your A / B and C are, they will definitely have to buffer the input signal with an op-amp in follower mode. Nah man, I do not approve that 4066 chip. And the MOSFET solution would have a resistance of maybe 20 mΩ, if the signal would be about 13 V then it would be right before the MOSFET would turn off and maybe have like 10 Ω. Not even close to 125 Ω.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thanks for checking that for me. I was looking at this MAXIM chip: [link](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX4066-MAX4066A-72194.pdf).
This datasheet doesn't specify the Pk-Pk switching like the TI one does.
It's looking like the MOSFET solution is a lot simpler, despite the higher part count. I've only really used them in power supplies before, at line level voltages I'm not likely to need heatsinks on them am I? Thanks again you've been super helpful!

Comment: @MathsThief I *doubt* you will need heatsinks, the resistances of the MOSFET's will most likely be very very low because the \$V_{GS}\$ will be pretty high. But only you know if you need heatsinks since you've never said what kind of signal you are routing. You would maybe need a heatsink if you were pulling through a couple of Ampere through the circuit. Here's some [MOSFET's](https://www.digikey.se/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278), go to the right hand side and change the rating for the \$V_{GS}\$ to 30 and above. Or just zener diode the VGS.

Comment: @MathsThief this will be my last comment, otherwise a moderator will come and move everything and link to a chat room (no joke). That MOSFET **would suffice**, though it's very bulky and expensive. If money and physical space is not an issue. Hit it. Personally I'd go for [these](https://www.mouser.se/search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=0virtualkey0virtualkeyNTR5103NT1G). But that's just a matter of taste. You can easily solder it onto a perfboard.

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding the question correctly that is actually a fairly complicated matrix. So correct me if I am wrong.

What you are looking for is this...

[image]

If you really only want the four permutations you can do that with a four pole four way switch like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fReoqn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, the permutations are much greater than four, six using all of them and more if you skip one, two, or three effects. If you want all of them then there are many ways to do that, some with micros, but a simple enough solution can be implemented with 13 reed relays, a bunch of diodes, and a rotary switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkLzkl.png)</sup>

[View Larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty686.png)

Note I only showed two switch positions, I am sure you can figure out the rest. I also added a bypass.

Comment: This is the reason people go digital …

Comment: Trevor's answer is perfect, but you should consider using a wiring panel and make the necessary connections with short cables instead of creating a wiring mess behind a switch. Signal quality should be far better either.

Comment: @Janka yes a nice digital interface with an accompanying computer or phone app to plug things around would be a nice little project.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I had looked at the 4P4T switch method and thought it seemed simple enough. The relay method looks great but I think the cost and power draw might be a bit much for my project. 
Is there someone where I could read about a digital implementation of this switching method? Would this be using logic and CMOS?