# What sort of switch to swap the order of two signal processors in series

Tags: switches, guitar-pedal

I'm building a guitar effects processor which is a 2-in-1 effect. Basically they're two separate circuits I've already built on perfboard which I want to put in the same box.

I haven't decided which one I want first and I would like a switch to be able to switch between the two.

So what sort of switch will I need? I'll need to switch between:

```
IN -> FX1 -> FX2 -> OUT
```

And

```
IN -> FX2 -> FX1 -> Out
```

Comment: This question is nearly a [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338776/signal-path-switching-for-effect-circuits), the only difference is that you are asking how to switch between two *black boxes* while the other question is asking how to switch between three *black boxes*.

Comment: Thanks, that did not come up in related questions. However due to the additional permutations that user requires, the responses are far more complicated than they need to be for my situation. I'm pretty sure this can be done with a 4PDT, I just need some help figuring out how.

Comment: Uhm.. okay, I will make an analogy of what just happened here. I showed how you can count from 0 to 10, but you only want to know how to count from 0 to 5. Instead of understanding the basic for counting 0 to 1.. to 2.. you want a specific solution for how to count from 0 to 5. I'll just say that you and everybody else would save time if you would go to the other question, **understand** how it works and then make your own solution. But hey, there's probably someone who will accommodate you. There's people for everything. I recommend you look at Trevor's answer, his is easier to understand.

Comment: I appreciate that but almost none of the answers in the other questions would have helped my situation, which requires a simple switch for two analog signal paths in a relatively small enclosure. Fortunately the other answer on this question solves my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with a 3-pole double-throw (3PDT) switch like one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/toggle-switches/201?k=&pkeyword=&pv130=6&FV=ffe000c9&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).
[image]
In the diagram below I've used 3 separate switches because circuitlab doesn't have a 3PDT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIKWoy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>